# How to validate a subset of JSON data differently based upon value of a particular property?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework. I have an API where I get JSON data. I have a list serializer where I am trying to validate a list out of the parent JSON. The list looks like this:

```
[{
 type:"integer",
 name: "Age",
 range: [18, 60]
},
{
 type: "string",
 name: "Email",
 pattern : "email"
},
{
 type: "date",
 name: "Joining Date",
 format: "mm-dd-yyyy"
}]
```

I have a serializer that takes care of the rest of the data. one of the property is this list which is taken care by a list serializer. Now for individual element in the list, the validation depends upon the type property.

For example: If the type is integer, I expect a range. If type is string, I expect a pattern.
If the type is date, I expect a format.

What is a good approach for validating such data ?

How do I verify that ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this pattern:

```
data = [{
    "type": "integer",
    "name": "Age",
    "range": [18, 60]
},
{
    "type": "string",
    "name": "Email",
    "pattern": "email"
},
{
    "type": "date",
    "name": "Joining Date",
    "format": "mm-dd-yyyy"
}]

rules = {
    "integer": {
        "must_contains": ["range"]
    },
    "string": {
        "must_contains": ["pattern"]
    }
}


class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass


class Validator(object):
    def __init__(self, rules):
        self.rules = rules

    @staticmethod
    def _check_contains_rule(rule, obj):
        for elem in rule.get("must_contains", ()):
            if not obj.get(elem):
                raise ValidationError("Object with type %s must contains %s!" % (obj["type"], elem))

    def validate(self, data):
        for obj in data:
            rule = self.rules.get(obj["type"])
            if rule:
                self._check_contains_rule(rule, obj)


v = Validator(rules)

v.validate(data)
```